# Python - Importing many libraries for multiple files convention

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-libraries, conventions, calling-convention

Regarding code structure and formatting, I can't find any clear information about this small nitpick relating to importing many modules at once.

Say I have two files, crudely named `solver.py` and `data.py`. Like most people, I have a set of standard modules that I import for each solver. Is it advisable to create a third module/textfile such as `importList` or `importList.py` which contains all the information such as `import xpackagex as xpx`? Should I just suck it up and copy over all of the imports for each file I write? Of course I am concerned about compatibility since for the main function where one could type `from importList import *` it would overwrite the any other choices, but it might make for some tidier looking code, particularly when many libraries are imported. Is there a standard approach for this?

Best wishes and thanks in advance.

Comment: _Should I just suck it up and copy over all of the imports for each file I write?_ That's probably the clearest/safest option. How many imports is it?

Comment: Typically I'd use somewhere around 40 imports. However, a lot of them can be put into a single line I guess. I was more looking to adhere to any convention for large project structures, however this does seem the safest option...